# Step debugging imported modules in Python with Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, python-import

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(some_data)
```

I put a breakpoint in the second line of this code and Visual Studio Code stops at this breakpoint. But when I try to step into the "read_csv" function vscode apparently performs a "step over".
I also tried setting a breakpoint inside the "read_csv" function but with the same result.

So how do I step into the mentioned function?

Comment: Seems to work for me. What exactly is `some_data`? Also, I assume this is Python 3?

Comment: some_data is a pandas DataFrame which got saved as csv. But this was just an example. The main point is, that I can't step inside this function. Yes, it is Python3 and I tried it under macOS as well as Ubuntu both running the latest version of vscode and Python3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To step into third-party code, set [`"debugOptions": ["DebugStdLib"]`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_debugoptions) in your `launch.json` configuration.

Comment: In my case it was `"debugStdLib": true` but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 27):

As of the April 2019 update debugStdLib changed to

`"justMyCode": false`

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_justmycode